# Why was I awarded an association bonus?

Tags: support, reputation

Half an hour ago, I was awarded a +100 association bonus on Math.SE. I don't know why. I have only one other StackExchange-account, an Area51-account that I have never really used (its reputation was 1 until I visited it fifteen minutes ago; then it received an association bonus from Math because my Math account has over 200 reputation, so that my Area51-account now has 101).

There seems to be no reason for me to receive the bonus, unless you're supposed to get the association bonus also on the account that has over 200 reputation. Even then, I don't know why I received the bonus *today*, since I have had over 200 reputation on Math.SE for some time.

The situation is similar to [I was prematurely awarded an association bonus](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3839/i-was-prematurely-awarded-an-association-bonus), but that issue is supposed to be solved.

Comment: Don't they have a pill for helping premature association? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Are you saying that you haven't been receiving e-mail offers for those?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen maybe you can share yours with Asaf...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the intentional behaviour, you get the reputation bonus on every site. The timing is probably related to visiting the site with the lower reputation, but I don't know exactly what triggers the check for awarding the bonus.

Comment: So I probably triggered the check somehow (don't know how exactly) which gave me +100 as intended, although in principle the check should have happened earlier. Right?

Comment: @DaanMichiels Yes, that is correct